# Question about James Stewart's Early Transcendentals 8th ed.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm reading this textbook to prepare for my first Calculus course, and I ran into this [image]

I don't understand how the function $g$ has the same limit as $y$. It's horizontal position is the same, but it's vertical position is different. With it's vertical position in mind, the limit of $g$ should be $2$ (especially since the point is filled and not empty).

Is this a mistake or am I not interpreting the authors message properly?

Comment: That's not how limits work. They intentionally picked a value far from the limit $=.5$ to illustrate that a function need not be *continuous* at a point for its limit to exist there.

Comment: The limit is about the values the graph is approaching as $x$ gets closer to $1$. Not the value that it actually has at $x=1$.

Comment: Ooh okay that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Limits of functions are independent of the function's value at any single point, even the limit point. They're determined by seeing where you end up if you take function values at points ever closer to the chosen point, excluding the point itself.

For example, if $f(1/n)$ = $1/n$ for all positive integers $n$, then it is already certain that the limit of $f$ at $0$ (if it exists) is $0$. Note that the value of $f(0)$ does not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For a limit to exist, $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)$, or in other words, what the function approaches from the right must equal what the function approaches from the left, which in the case of g(x) is still 0.5.